# if else condition in angularjs to compare string and int value

Tags: angularjs, if-statement

I want to check if both the font and the fontSize is undefined which was sent from the client side.When the user do not select the font or font size, it pass the value undefined. These conditions work well when only one of them (font or font size) is undefined, but when both of them are undefined, I recieve an error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'font' of undefined
    at Scope.StylesCtrl.$scope.addStyles (http://0.0.0.0:8080/app/edit/styles/StylesCtrl.js:26:38)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13231:15), <anonymous>:4:317)
    at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://0.0.0.0:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:23411:17)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://0.0.0.0:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15916:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://0.0.0.0:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16016:25)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://0.0.0.0:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:23416:23)
    at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://0.0.0.0:8080/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4435:9)
    at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (http://0.0.0.0:8080/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4121:28) undefined
```

Below is my if else conditions in the server side,

```
if(font == undefined && fontSize == undefined){ //doesn't work
        console.log("font");
        updateFile(main, [
            {rule: ".made-easy-themeColor", target: "color", replacer: color}
        ], function (err) {
            console.log((err));
        });
    }

    else if(font == undefined){ //work well
        updateFile(main, [
            {rule: ".made-easy-themeColor", target: "color", replacer: color},
            {rule: ".made-easy-themeFontSize", target: "font-size", replacer: fontSize + "em"}
        ], function (err) {
            console.log((err));
        });
    }
    else if(fontSize == undefined){ //work well
        updateFile(main, [
            {rule: ".made-easy-themeColor", target: "color", replacer: color},
            {rule: ".made-easy-themeFont", target: "font-family", replacer: font}
        ], function (err) {
            console.log((err));
        });
    }

    else{ //work well
        updateFile(main, [
            {rule: ".made-easy-themeColor", target: "color", replacer: color},
            {rule: ".made-easy-themeFont", target: "font-family", replacer: font},
            {rule: ".made-easy-themeFontSize", target: "font-size", replacer: fontSize + "em"}
        ], function (err) {
            console.log((err));
        });

    }
```

This is the html code in front end

```
 <h3 ng-style="{'font-family': styles.textSize.font, 'font-size': styles.textSize.size + 'px'}">Text Is</h3>
```

This is the controller to send data to the server

```
$scope.addStyles = function(styles) {
            $scope.fontdata = {
                appId: "55c0ace94aa248735d75b140",
                header: styles.uploadme,
                color: styles.myColor,
                font: styles.textSize.font,
                fontSize: styles.textSize.size
            };
                stylesService.editStyles($scope.fontdata)
                    .success(function (res) {
                        console.log("success");
                    })
        };
```

Is there any problem with my if else statements? or is it because I am comparing string value(font) and an int value(fontSize)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're not initializing your model objects on the `$scope`. It has nothing to do w/your server side if/else... As @Hrishi points out, it's a Javascript error :)

To fix it, you need to initialize the object `styles.textSize` on your scope.

The reason is that Angular (`ng-model`?) will create this object for you **when the user types into one of the inputs**. But when the user doesn't type anything, `styles.textSize` never gets defined.

Just guessing here, b/c we can't see your template or the rest of the code in your controller, but fix it do something like this:

```
$scope.styles = {
  textSize: {
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack clearly says that error is in the StyleCntrl.js at below location
at Scope.StylesCtrl.$scope.**addStyles** (http://0.0.0.0:8080/app/edit/styles/**StylesCtrl.js:26:38)**

and it apppears to be at below line inside addStyles function
**font: styles.textSize.font**

The issue is because **textSize** in styles object is undefined and if you try to read any property on undefined object java-script will always throw an error as

***TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined***

Comment: How can I make it work, how can I define it(textSize)?

Comment: just initialize you model in scope with empty object as below

$scope.styles = {
  textSize: {}
}